# Download an entire blog for offline reading / archival (without using RSS feed)

Tags: rss

I want to download an entire wordpress blog to read offline. Is there any easy way to do this specifically for wordpress blogs? I don't want to use RSS feeds, since the blog I wish to download does not give the entire post in its RSS feed.

If there's no easy way to do this specifically for wordpress blogs, any suggestions for a good generic website downloading tool?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I've needed to download a site for offline viewing, I've used [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). It's not WP specific, but it's always done the job for me and has been around for a long time.

Comment: [Sitesucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html) is a similar app if you're on OS X and don't want to install MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

To read website offline, you have to grabb the website in you PC. So i have 2 options to do this

1. [**HTTRACK**](https://www.httrack.com/)
   HTTRACK is chmapion for copying the contents from the entire site. HTTRACK can even grab the needed pieces to make a website with active code content work offline.
   This is the tool you need. Thi sis my suggested tool than others
2. **Internet Download Manager**
   Internet Download Manager (IDM) is bascially downloading tool which allow user to grab entire site.
   Here you can find the steps how to grab the website with IMD Grabber for offline use
   https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm-grabber/grabber_wizard.html

   One thing, IMD is coming with 1 month free trails after that its cost you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Print My Blog plugin to create a PDF of your site. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/print-my-blog/